# Passing dictionary to map function

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, dictionary

I have a points feature collection and have added the latitude and longitude to each point's properties as well. Now I want to do a processing on each point and want to use the map function. The processing function will extract some Landsat 8 time series and do an analysis, and the analysis subfunction should be fed with the parameters in a dictionary format and will return a dictionary.

```
def getModel(pointFeature):
    args = pointFeature.toDictionary()
    lon = args.get('longitude')
    lat = args.get('latitude')
    point = ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat])
    # Create image collection
    l8_collection = ee.ImageCollection(
        'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').filterBounds(point).filterDate('2015-01-01', '2018-01-01')
    info = l8_collection.getRegion(point, 30).getInfo()
    header = info[0]
    data = np.array(info[1:])
    results = analysis_function(header, data)
    return ee.Feature(None, results)

Results = points.map(getModel)
```

But I get the below error and it traces to the line `info = l8_collection.getRegion(point, 30).getInfo()`:

```
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Failed to decode JSON.
Error: Field 'value' of object '{"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}' is missing or null.
Object: {"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}.
```

I think it is all about client/server variable passing in GEE, but I couldn't manage to solve it. I tried to add getInfo() after calculations of Lat and Lon or casting the Lat and Lon to ee.Number() but the problem persists.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `getInfo()` inside a `map` function. Also, you cannot create a `numpy` array inside a `map` function. So this is leading nowhere. I'd do something like this:

```python
def getModel(pointFeature, ini_list):
    args = pointFeature.toDictionary()
    lon = args.get('longitude')
    lat = args.get('latitude')
    point = ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat])
    # Create image collection
    l8_collection = ee.ImageCollection(
        'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').filterBounds(point).filterDate('2015-01-01', '2018-01-01')
    info = l8_collection.getRegion(point, 30)
    return ee.List(ini_list).add(info)

info_list = ee.List(points.iterate(getModel, ee.List([]))

feat_list = []
for point_data in info_list.getInfo(): 
    header = point_data[0]
    data = np.array(point_data[1:])
    results = analysis_function(header, data)
    feat_list.append(ee.Feature(None, results))

Results = ee.FeatureCollection(feat_list)
```

The approach would be different if `analysis_function` would be a function made entirely in Earth Engine.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Yes I see my mistake. But the analysis function is an imported one and I can not change or rewrite it. So because I should use a for loop anyway and it is the analysis part that takes time, there is no point is using map or iterate techniques in my case. Right?

Comment: If `analysis_function` doesn't use Earth Engine API functions but local libraries then no, you won't be able to call it from inside a `map` function. You could try to "translate" that function to use only EE API, then you could use it in a `map` function, and you'd probably save a lot of time